# Tmux returns error and error code 1 is displayed in terminal prompt

Tags: linux, terminal, tmux

[image]

When I run `tmux` my terminal prompt displays an error code, and I'm not sure why. I don't really know how to see where that error code is printed out, and I don't even really know where to begin. It's an error code 1 I'm assuming but I don't know what could even cause that for Tmux specifically.

Any information you can provide to point me into digging in further is appreciated and if there is any output I can provide to improve my question, please let me know.

Comment: The error messages display might be too brief. Enter the following command: `tmux set-option -g display-time 10000` and restart tmux.

Comment: Looks like it's a simple error, but I've never seen this post as an error code in powerline before, and I've been using both on other systems for some time?
```$ tmux set-option -g display-time 10000
no server running on /tmp/tmux-1000/default```

Appears to be correct (and as I would expect because there is no server running) but I don't know why that would pass output to the terminal status codes.

I'm using both ```tmux``` and ```tmux new``` when no servers are running and both produce that same output. Confused that it would say that when I'm explicitly starting a new session/server?